# Should a queue be automatically created when messages are forwarded by divert to an address that has no queues?

Tags: activemq-artemis

I created two addresses ADDRESS.IN, ADDRESS.OUT and also a divert

```xml
        <diverts>
            <divert name="DIVERT">
                <address>ADDRESS.IN</address>
                <forwarding-address>ADDRESS.OUT</forwarding-address>
                <exclusive>true</exclusive>
            </divert>
        </diverts>
```

When sending messages to the address ADDRESS.IN, they disappear, the queue in the address ADDRESS.OUT is not automatically created, although the address parameter `autoCreateQueues=true`.

Artemis version 2.17.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diverts do not automatically create addresses or queues.